# EBNF / parboiled: how to translate regexp into PEG?

Tags: java, parsing, ebnf, parboiled

This is a question both specific to the parboiled parser framework, and to BNF/PEG in general.

Let's say I have the fairly simple regular expression

```
^\\s*([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)\\s*=\\s*(\\S+)\\s*$
```

which represents the pseudo-EBNF of

```
<line>               ::= <ws>? <identifier> <ws>? '=' <nonwhitespace> <ws>?
<ws>                 ::= (' ' | '\t' | {other whitespace characters})+
<identifier>         ::= <identifier-head> <identifier-tail>
<identifier-head>    ::= <letter> | '_'    
<identifier-tail>    ::= (<letter> | <digit> | '_')*
<letter>             ::= ('A'..'Z') | ('a'..'z')
<digit>              ::= '0'..'9'
<nonwhitespace>      ::= ___________
```

How would you define nonwhitespace (one or more characters that aren't whitespace) in EBNF?

For those of you familiar with the Java parboiled library, how could you implement a rule that defines nonwhitespace?

Comment: Wait, where are the repetition quantifiers? As far as I can read the grammar there can be only one letter etc

Comment: see `identifier-tail`

Comment: Uh, OK, I was trying to read it as an EBNF grammar where the `*` would have been before the paren...

Answer (score 5):

You are stuck with the conventions of your lexical generator for specifying character ranges and operations on character ranges.

Many lexer generators accept  hex values (something like 0x) to represent characters, so you might write:

```
 '0'..'9'
 0x30..\0x39
```

for digits.

For nonwhitespace, you need to know which character set you are using.  For 7 bit ASCII, nonwhitespace is conceptually all the printing characters:

```
0x21..\0x7E
```

For ISO8859-1:

```
( 0x21..\0x7E | 0x80-0xFF )
```

You can decide for yourself if the character codes above 0x80 are spaces or not (is non-breaking space a space?).  You also get to decide about the status of the control characters 0x0..0x1F.   Is tab (0x9) a whitespace character? How about CR 0xD and LF 0xA? How about the ETB control character?

Unicode is harder, because its a huge set, and your list gets big and messy.  *C'est la vie*.  Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is used to build parsers for a wide variety of languages, and has to support lexers for ASCII, ISO8859-z for lots of z's, and Unicode.  Rather than write complicated "additive" regular expression ranges, DMS allows *subtractive* regular expressions, and so we can write:

```
 <UniCodeLegalCharacters>-<UniCodeWhiteSpace>
```

which is much easier to understand and gets it right on the first try.

Answer (score 2):

In EBNF I would simply define nonwhitespace as any character that isn't whitespace:

```
nonwhitespace ::= anycharacter - whitespace
```

This requires that you have a 'anycharacter' literal that defines the entire range of possible symbols, and a clear definition of which characters are whitespace.

In Parboiled you can do this using the `TestNot` and `ANY` Rules,  so for example
nonwhitespace would be defined as any character which doesn't match the WhiteSpace() Rule:

```
Sequence( TestNot(WhiteSpace()) , ANY )
```